# How to find the y from given x on fit line?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, data-fitting

I ploted a fit line using numpy and matplotlib of a graph and I need to find the spesific y value for a x value that I determine on the line. Is it possible?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,7), dpi=600)

a, b = np.polyfit(x.x, x.v, 1)

plt.plot(x.x, x.v, linestyle='none', marker='v', color='#33E0FF', markeredgecolor='#FD8100', markersize=10)
plt.plot(x.x, a*x.x + b, color='#FF5733')

plt.xlabel("x(cm)")
plt.ylabel("v^2(cm^2/s^2")

plt.grid(True)

plt.xticks(np.arange(20, 81, 5))
plt.yticks(np.arange(900, 3500, 250))

plt.show()
```

this is graph code and i want to find which y values for x=55

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `a*55 + b` or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Your a,b are the coefficients of the line you fitted.

you are plotting the line in this line of code:

```
plt.plot(x.x, a*x.x + b, color='#FF5733')
```

so if you want a y value for a specific x it would look something like this:

```
y_x_1 = a*x_1+b
```